# How to insert unknown amount of colums in mysql using PHP PDO

Tags: php, mysql, pdo

Currently, I am using this code: PHP PDO Insert data

```
try {

    // prepare sql and bind parameters
    $stmt = $conn->prepare("INSERT INTO TABLE (firstname) 
    VALUES (:firstname, :lastname, :email)");
    $stmt->bindParam(':firstname', $firstname);    
    // insert a row
    $firstname = "John";
    $stmt->execute();
    echo "New records created successfully";
    }
```

And it works perfectly fine.

My problem: I have 5 columns like: `tag1,tag2,tag3,tag4,tag5`

This is how, i get values from an API (array) and echo them

```
for ($i=0;$i<count($response["tag"]);$i++    )
{
echo "  ".$response["tag"][$i]["name"]." ";
}
```

Now, If the array only send 2 tag values (i.e: `["tag"][0]["name"] and ["tag"][1]["name"]`

Then i want to insert the value in only `tag1 & tag2 columns`

But looks like I cannot use forloop inside the insert data code. I need some help here.

Comment: Learn about normalization and you solve your problem

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If this is the way you have to do it (as opposed to normalization) then something like

```
$data = [];
$binds = [];
for ($i=0;$i<count($response["tag"]);$i++    )
{
    //echo "  ".$response["tag"][$i]["name"]." ";
    $columns[] = "tag".$i;
    $binds[] = ":tag".$i;
}

$sql = 'insert into tableName ('.implode(',',$columns).')'.
        ' values ('.implode(',',$binds).')';
echo $sql;
$stmt = $conn->prepare($sql);
for ($i=0;$i<count($response["tag"]);$i++    )  {
    $stmt->bindParam($binds[i], $response["tag"][i]["name"]);
}
```

The first foreach builds a sql statement such as

```
insert into tableName (tag0,tag1) values (:tag0,:tag1)
```

(Adjust table names etc for your database).  The second foreach binds the values passed in with each place holder in the statement.

Comment: Hey, I figured out another way. See my answer. It is very simple. But I don't know, which way is better? 

Does my way have a considerable disadvantage?

Comment: This is what $sql echo `insert into TABLE (tag0,tag1) values (:tag0,:tag1)` And this is the error i got `Error: SQLSTATE[HY093]: Invalid parameter number: Columns/Parameters are 1-based`

Answer (score 1):

If you have not normalized data, you can have one `TEXT` type column in your DB and when you receive data from API `serialize array` or `encode to JSON` and save it in DB.

Comment: 1.) What I need to type on google, to learn normalized data? I know nothing about it till now. 

2.) I want different columns for each tag, i do not want to put all tags in 1 text coloumn

Comment: use rows over columns. You say you have one table with 5 columns. Create a headers table and a rows table and insert as many tags as you need in the rows table. That is normalization. But I have a feeling that you don't want this either

Answer (score 0):

I tried this and worked. But not sure, if it is good idea or not.

```
try {

    // prepare sql and bind parameters
    $stmt = $conn->prepare("INSERT INTO TABLE (firstname,tag1,tag2,tag3,tag4,tag5) 
    VALUES (:firstname,:tag1,:tag2,:tag3,:tag4,:tag5)");
    $stmt->bindParam(':firstname', $firstname);
    $stmt->bindParam(':tag1', $tag1);
    $stmt->bindParam(':tag2', $tag2);
    $stmt->bindParam(':tag3', $tag3);
    $stmt->bindParam(':tag4', $tag4);
    $stmt->bindParam(':tag5', $tag5);

    // insert a row
    $firstname = "John";
if ( ($response["tag"][0]["name"]) != ""        )
$tag1= "".$response["tag"][0]["name"]."";
if ( ($response["tag"][1]["name"]) != ""        )
$tag2= "".$response["tag"][1]["name"]."";
if ( ($response["tag"][2]["name"]) != ""        )
$tag3= "".$response["tag"][2]["name"]."";
if ( ($response["tag"][3]["name"]) != ""        )
$tag4= "".$response["tag"][3]["name"]."";
if ( ($response["tag"][4]["name"]) != ""        )
$tag5= "".$response["tag"][4]["name"]."";
    $stmt->execute();
    echo "New records created successfully";
    }
```

Comment: Turn on error reporting with warning level and see what happens. If you don't want to normalize the database Nigel's answers is better than yours. FYI the tag1..5 columns will need a default value, null will do